# Why doesn't it recognize the Leaf command: #loop

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I am starting out with an almost blank project and I can render a simple page from welcome.leaf using this:

```
router.get("view") { req -> Future<View> in
    let leaf = try req.make(LeafRenderer.self)
    return leaf.render("welcome")
}
```

However, if I put **#loop** into welcome.leaf I get this message:

```
[ ERROR ] TemplateError.serialize: No tag named `loop` is registered. in /Users/david/CloudStation/XcodeProjects/Vapor3affordat/Resources/Views/welcome.leaf line: 24 column: 1 range: 580..<785 (TemplateSerializer.swift:59)
```

Why does it not recognize the loop leaf command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Leaf 3 `#loop()` has been renamed to `#for`. The syntax has also changed. Vapor 2:

`#loop(things, "thing")`

In Vapor 3 this becomes

`#for(thing in things)`